# Create a new form instance inside parent with the ability to access the parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, mdiparent, formborderstyle

I tried to create a new form inside the Parent. I set `FormBorderStyle` to `none`.

When I am adjusting MDIParent to the `myForm`, it gave me a sick looking error like this:

```
System.ArgumentException : The given Form is not being recalled as a MdiContainer.
```

This is my code for creating a new Windows Form.

```
FrmHome myForm = new FrmHome ();
myForm.TopLevel = false;
pnlContainer.Controls.Add(myForm);
myForm.Show();
```

Comment: A new Windows Forms _application_? Like are you loading another EXE or dynamically compiling another application? Or do you just mean a new form?

Comment: I mean a new Form

Answer (score 2):

The Mdi parent must have it's `IsMdiContainer` property set to `True`.

You can set this property at design time in your main form or runtime :-

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.MdiParent = this;
f1.Show();
```

`Form1` is the name of the form that you want to show.

**Form.IsMdiContainer Property**

> Property Value
>   Boolean
>   true if the form is a container for MDI child forms; otherwise, false. 
>   The default is false.